# AS3 External .as Class Cannot Access Stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've looked everywhere and help me I cannot find an answer to this, I'm sure it's quite simple...

I have a file Main.fla (Download below as Runner.fla) with the movie clips Floor and Runner on the stage, and Abdomen and Legs inside of Runner and many more smaller movie clips inside of Abdomen and Legs. Under properties I have "Core" without the quotations typed into the Class field. I have another file called Core.as with all of my source code. Every time I execute (Test build) either file the program window opens as normal but I get numerous errors about how Runner and Floor are undefined. I suppose I have to import them somehow into Core.as, but I can't figure out how.

Edit: Download links:
Runner.fla: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7rencmi801pwfki/Runner.fla
Core.as: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pt0lnuj2b3jolej/Core.as

Note that the code IS NOT FUNCTIONAL. I know that it doesn't work and is going to blow up, I need help in dealing with the initial undefined errors, I can deal with the other stuff. Also there's no code in Runner.fla except for commented out stuff. And Vesper, can you clarify what you mean by I should put all my code in the timeline? Do you mean in the stage in Runner.fla?

Comment: It's likely your on-stage instances are not named `Floor` and `Runner`, also you should reference them from the timeline code for this. (I'd not use timeline, but it's just me.)

Comment: It sounds like 'Core' is your document class. If you want to refer to 'Floor' and 'Runner' when they are already on-stage in your .fla, you have to call them by their instance names which you can assign in the properties panel. Do that, then post some code and we can deal with your next errors.

Comment: OK... I think I'm doing the basics right, I'll post links to my files for detail (It still doesn't work). If you don't see that above, hold on a minute.

Answer (score 1):

In order for a Class to access stage, it should inherit from the DisplayObject class (MovieClip, Sprite) or you could also pass **stage** as a class parameter.